# SQL Server - How to remove duplicates within select query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do you delete duplicate records based on multiple paramaters from a select query?

I have a complex query that returns these, and I need to remove duplicates based on IdRow, IdAudience and IdAb, so in the case below I would need to remove Ids 1 and 3:

| Id | IdRow | IdAudience | IdAb | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | 2836 | 1 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | 2836 | 1 |
| 3 | 560540 | NULL | NULL | 77 |
| 4 | 560540 | NULL | NULL | 77 |

But how do I do this from a select query?

Comment: Please specify what to do with Id and Quantity. Should we pick one, and if so, which one? Should we sum quantities? Provide desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this in a subquery as below

```
delete from yourtable where Id not in 
(
SELECT top 1000 MAX(Id) AS Id
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY IdRow, IdAudience, IdAb, Quantity
ORDER BY Id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id, IdRow, IdAudience, IdAb, Quantity
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY IdRow, IdAudience, IdAb, Quantity
ORDER BY 1;
```

This assumes that, given a set of 2 or more duplicates, you want to retain the single record with the max `Id` value.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use the ever popular ROW_NUMBER() function to filter out the duplicates as well:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdRow, IdAudience,IdAb ORDER BY Id DESC) RN
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
```